# Boolean difference operation and bevel problems in blender 2.9

Tags: modeling, modifiers, bevel

I am very new to blender, please help.

I am trying to make a hole in part 1, by subtracting part 2 from it using boolean difference. But when i do that nothing happens, but in wireframe mode it shows that the boolean happened (see pic).

When boolean difference did not work i made a union and selected all the faces and deleted them, and got the hole. But bevel is not applying on it uniformly after that. I have tried applying the scale, rotation, and transformations, also flipped the normals both on 1 and 2, but nothing worked. (the other holes were made by using part 3, it had similar bevel problem, which was solved by recalculating the normals.)

What are the edges protruding out of the mesh? (the bevel changes its curvature around those two axis, marked by arrows in the pic)

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: as Zelig63 says it might be because you didn't delete the original object and it makes you think that the boolean didn't work, if it doesn't fix the problem, share your file: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Answer (score 0):

When the difference boolean modifier is applied, delete part 2. You have to do this because the modifier doesn't delete it automatically. So even after having successfully applied the modifier, the hole doesn't appear because it is still filled with the original part.

Comment: Could you please add more to your answer to prevent it from getting deleted? It also helps the question to provide a little more detail.